# Build Single Azure Devops Artifact from multiple projects

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

How can I build multiple projects in succession and then have all of those projects build a single artifact? I'm not sure of the syntax available as it doesn't match the documentation, exactly. Here is what i'm trying to do but i cannot syntactically do so.  Please, not the multiple projects that would be built in the projects key's value.

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Front-End'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/FirstUIProject.csproj', '**/SecondUIProject.csproj', '**/NthUIProject.csproj'  
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'


# Publish the artifact
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: False
    projects: '**/FirstUIProject.csproj', '**/SecondUIProject.csproj', '**/NthUIProject.csproj'  
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/UI'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# Publish the artifact for the pipelines to use
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publishing UI Artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/UI' 
    artifactName: 'UI Build Artifact'
```

I tried to create multiple projects that would be zipped up into a single build artifact to be published and downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DotNetCoreCLI@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) documentation in the projects parameter

"... You can use wildcards (e.g. **/*.csproj for all .csproj files in all subfolders). ..."
It means that for the projects from your example, you can use the following matching pattern:

```
 projects: '**/*UIProject.csproj'
```

If you need a more advanced pattern you can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops).